# Get Xml Text node ID

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, docx, xmlnode

I'm trying to parse through the document.xml file of a .docx file. I would like to search for Text and then return the node that text is located so I can then move up to the parent node and insert a new node type. This is what I have so far, I have been trying to use SelectSingle node but i can't seem to get the path right("the path is correct up until /w:body). So I would like to just search for the text and get the node that way if thats possible.

```
NameTable nt = new NameTable();
XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
nsManager.AddNamespace("w", wordmlNamespace);

// Get the document part from the package.
// Load the XML in the document part into an XmlDocument instance.
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument(nt);
xdoc.Load(wdDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream());
XmlNode ALL = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/w:document/w:body/w:p/w:r[w:t='[ALL]']", nsManager);
if (ALL != null)
{
    XmlElement vanish = xdoc.CreateElement( "//w:vanish /");
    XmlNode topNode = ALL.ParentNode.ParentNode;
    XmlNode topParentNode = topNode.ParentNode;
    topParentNode.InsertBefore(vanish,topParentNode.FirstChild);

}

// Save the document XML back to its document part.
xdoc.Save(wdDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your xpath should read  `"//w:t='[ALL]']"`.